# Outlook - get message id with javascript?

Tags: javascript, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I made a question yesterday, asking to get the "id" from the outlook mail URL, like this:

```
https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/inbox/id/AQQkADAwATM0MDAAMS0xZGUwLTNjMTAtMDACLTAwCgAQAB%2FnQ1lgT6dDlqIakp3j4qk%3D
```

But it turns out that that is not the message id, for some reason.

Is there any way to get the actual message id with javascript?
Im using this to interact with the microsoft graph api. [Have a look here to see what i'm trying to do](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#code-try-2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('bb8775a4-4d8c-42cf-a1d4-4d58c2bb668f')/messages(sender,subject)",
"value": [
    {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADHcgC8Hl9tRZ/hc1wEUs1TAAAwR4Hg\"",
        "id": "AAMkAGUAAAwTW09AAA=",
        "subject": "Welcome to our group!",
        ...
    }
]
}
```

Get a list of messages, and for every message, if the conversationID matches the outlook ID (with / replaced with -) then that is the email

Answer (score 0):

Message id is the id of any message you get using [List Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). The Graph API follows REST API design. I suggest you do the resource navigation through Graph. Don't copy id from outlook client and use on Graph.

List messages:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('bb8775a4-4d8c-42cf-a1d4-4d58c2bb668f')/messages(sender,subject)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADHcgC8Hl9tRZ/hc1wEUs1TAAAwR4Hg\"",
            "id": "AAMkAGUAAAwTW09AAA=",
            "subject": "Welcome to our group!",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Then get one message:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkAGUAAAwTW09AAA=
{
    "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('cd209b0b-3f83-4c35-82d2-d88a61820480')/messages(subject,body,bodyPreview,uniqueBody)/$entity",
    "@odata.etag":"W/\"CQAAABYAAABmWdbhEgBXTophjCWt81m9AAAoZYj4\"",
    "id":"AAMkAGUAAAwTW09AAA=",
    "subject":"Welcome to our group!",
    "bodyPreview":"Welcome to our group, Dana!",
    ...
}
```

Comment: that seems to work, but doesn't give me all the emails. I called it and it returned 9. (mostly in the Other folder) Is there any way to get all messages?

Comment: Kindly note that responses in List Messages is paginated, if it returns `@odata.nextLink` property, you need to use that to view more messages. You can also use the [$top](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#odata-system-query-options) operator to specify the number of records returned. Check [Use query parameters to customize responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#odata-system-query-options) for further details. If this answer solves your case, please accept and open a new question for any further issues. Folks will be happy to answer.